# Can I play `A scale` song on a `C scale` harmonica?

Tags: scales, harmonica

Here is how to play a `C scale` on a harmonica. But I found a song which is in the `A scale`. So, is this possible: to play the `A scale` song on the same harmonica? If so, What would the table look like? or how can I change the `C scale` to `A scale`? Is there any algorithm to do so? For example, when I change it to `E scale`, is there any equation to do so? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean A Major, I suppose?

Comment: @Luke, you raise a good point. You wanna write an answer about relative minor? I was about to add more, but I think I've milked it enough. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can play the A scale on a C harmonica. But you'll have to <del>bend</del> overblow all the C's (♯1 (or use ♭2, if ♯1 is not available)) F's (♯4 (or substitute ♭5)) and G's (♯5 (or ♭6)) because the A Major scale goes: A B C♯ D E F♯ G♯ A.

For Blues, don't raise the G. Use the A mixolydian scale instead: A B C♯ D E F♯ G A.

Or, for *harder* Blues, use the A minor pentatonic: A C D E G A.

For *really hard* Blues, play *the blue notes*. But you have to find them *in the middle* of the bend because they exist partway between the notes of the diatonic scales. In A, there's one between C and C♯ and between E and F♯ and between F♯ and G.

To learn the "algorithm" for finding the sharps and flats in a scale, read about The Circle of Fifths/Fourths, Key Signatures, Key Modulation, and maybe even The Pythagorean Comma.

Using the Circle of Fifths, you'll see that E is one step farther from C (no sharps/flats) than A (3 sharps). So it has 4 sharps. The same three from the A scale plus the new *leading tone* (Major Seventh) D♯ instead of D.

I've heard it's common for a player to have several harmonicas in different keys. Usually they're not too-many steps (fourths or fifths) away from C. So a small set would be C, F (or B♭), and G (or D). It's also common for a player to choose the harmonica that's keyed to the fifth to make the mixolydian (♭7) <-> ionian (Major 7) transition simpler. So for a song in A, you'd grab the D harmonica. This can help put the melody in the *sweet spot*. [*This paragraph assembled from heresay, use at own risk.*]

Comment: your last para. is o.k., as in ,playing with a blues band, songs in E for example, you'd use an A harp, as sucking this will produce a sort of E9 chord, allbeit without the root.

Comment: Is this overblowing suggestion just theoretical or do real players do this to change keys? I'm not asking about the blues scale stuff. That part is understood.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I've seen it done in youtube videos. But I've never been able to do it myself. I'd probably bend down to get those notes, to be honest.

Comment: @LuserDroog, can you share a video link? The only example I can find is this: https://youtu.be/_mgBmwxhJuA?t=6m45s. In the video he only deals with one altered note as apposed to three altered notes to get A major from C major. It also doesn't seem like a practical technique for changing key.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off getting a harp in the appropriate key - much less bother - or - get a chromatic harmonica (with a button at the side ) to give all the # and b neccessary, so you  can play in any key you like. They're often based in C maj. anyway, so can still work like your existing one.